# No Syntax Highlighting of Package Functions

Tags: front-end, syntax-highlighting

Lately, my installation of Mathematica has decided not to highlight any symbols loaded from packages. The picture below is a good representation of this:

[image]

where after loading both `` PhysicalConstants` `` and `` Units` `` `BohrRadius`, `Meter`, and `Angstrom` should all be black. Yet, they retain their "unknown symbol" color. This occurs for all packages and is persistent across restarting the front-end and rebooting the entire system. Any suggestions for correcting this?

I am running the student version of 8.0.4 on MacOS 10.6.8.

Comment: What happens when you deselect highlighting of "Global symbols that have no value assigned" in the Preferences dialog?  Does my suggestion below function then?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard no it doesn't.

Comment: I just want to add this happens *constantly* to me, especially if I have aborted a calculation using Command + period. The only remedy is to restart Mathematica entirely (restarting the kernel alone does not work). I'm pretty sure this is just a bug in Mathematica.

Comment: @Guillochon yes, I have that happen, also. But, this was persisting beyond restarting mathematica.

Comment: Was this ever resolved?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard only in the short term. It still recurs. I've given up fixing it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know what is causing your problem, but presumably you can still specially color the symbols in those contexts [as I do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6136694/618728).  For example:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, 
  AutoStyleOptions -> {"SymbolContextStyles" ->
     {"Units`" -> Brown, "PhysicalConstants`" -> Orange}
   }
]
```

---

Since the above suggestion doesn't have effect on your machine even when you deselect highlighting of "Global symbols that have no value assigned" in the Preferences dialog, it sounds like something is really broken. Obviously backing things up first, try deleting the user configuration files.

Comment: No dice. I think the highlighter is viewing them as not having any values assigned to them, so it is not moving off of the blue.

Comment: @rcollyer I'm doing it directly in the Options Inspector (or perhaps I should say the settings reside in the FrontEnd/init.m file), but really it's just a matter of preference, isn't it?

Comment: Which files in particular? The `$UserBaseDirectory/FrontEnd/8.0 Caches`?

Comment: I moved both `$UserBaseDirectory/FrontEnd/8.0 Caches` and `init.m` from `$UserBaseDirectory/FrontEnd`, restarted, and it appears to have worked. I'm wondering what got fubared ... Any way, edit you comment in to your answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: No real customizations to speak of.

Comment: It seems it is something in `init.m` that is going funny, but I'll be damned if I know what it is.

Comment: Here's a question for you. If I wanted to highlight ``Global` ``, that is straightforward, but what if I have the default `Context` set to notebook or cell grouping, how would I go about automatically highlighting the user defined symbols? Let me know if I should post this as a separate question.

Comment: @rcollyer Give me some time to think about that, please.

Comment: I figured it wouldn't be an immediate answer, so take as much time as you need.

Comment: @rcollyer I never thought of a solution and frankly it slipped my mind.  Did you post a new question about this?

Comment: slipped my mind, too, so no I haven't.