# Running a package automatically when it's saved

Tags: front-end

When developing some new code (eg. a function to analyse something) I usually make a .m and .nb file. The code goes in to .m is then called from the .nb.

But sometimes I forget to run the package after saving and then spend some time wondering why my code changes don't have the desired effect.

**Is there a way to run a package automatically after it's saved?**

Basically I would like that when I press [Ctrl]+S the package is saved and that the effect of this button being pressed is achieved.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Currently I put `Import["MyPackage.m"]` at the top of the evaluation cell I'm currently working on in the notebook. Perhaps I could also abuse $Pre for this, but then the package would get imported on every cell evaluation (which is a bit needles).

**EDIT**

Well, this is what I have so far based on [Chirs's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5418/745) answer

```
FrontEndExecute[
 FrontEnd`AddMenuCommands[
  "Save", {Delimiter, 
   MenuItem["Save and Run &Package", 
    FrontEnd`KernelExecute[NotebookSave[SelectedNotebook[]];
     If[FileExtension[NotebookFileName[SelectedNotebook[]]] == 
       "m",(*then*)
      Get[NotebookFileName[SelectedNotebook[]]];
      ];
     ], MenuKey["S", Modifiers -> {"Control"}], 
    System`MenuEvaluator -> Automatic]}]]
```

Comment: If you are willing to use Wolfram Workbench for package development, it reloads the package automatically when you save it. You can also customize what is being reloaded.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Yes, I was afraid that would be one of the answers. I tried to start using the workbench about twice, but it always wanted to do things it's way and not my way (especially regarding the layout of files). Perhaps I was doing something wrong and it's time to give it another go.

Comment: @ Ajasja - re. your edit, instead of `If[FileExtension...]` you could use `Function[filecheck, If[filecheck =!= $Failed, If[FileExistsQ[#],
      Get[#]]]& @ StringJoin[StringDrop[filecheck, -3], ".m"]] @
 Quiet[NotebookFileName[SelectedNotebook[]]]`. This checks if the current notebook is saved, then checks for existence of a package before trying to load it.

Comment: @ Ajasja - ah, I see you are not coding in a notebook, but wouldn't that be easier?

Comment: @ChrisDegnen I find coding in a package has a number of advantages: Code is not auto-rearranged as you type and it's simple to have a package under version control.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will assign a 'Save and Run` function to control-shift F:

```
FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`AddMenuCommands["Save",
  {MenuItem["Save and &Run",
    FrontEnd`KernelExecute[NotebookSave[SelectedNotebook[]];
     Get[StringJoin[
       StringDrop[NotebookFileName[SelectedNotebook[]], -3], ".m"]]],
    MenuKey["F", Modifiers -> {"Control", "Shift"}],
    System`MenuEvaluator -> Automatic]}]]
```

To test, include the following as an initialisation cell in the working notebook (with auto-create package):

```
test := Print["Change this text, then execute Save and Run and run test"]
```

By using `AddMenuCommands` the menu addition only appears when the procedure is run, so doesn't affect the standard setup.  It only needs to be run once, and the menu addition disappears upon restart.  The 'Save and Run' command is placed under Save on the File menu.

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't seem to run the package in the front end, only saves it. (All the symbols remain blue, but the package is saved).

Comment: @Ajasja The blue to black change isn't necessarily a [good indicator](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4886/52) if a package was loaded. Check to see if the definition is visible via `?FunctionName`.

Comment: @ChrisDegnen Aha, I want to run the package when I save it, not run the package when I save the notebook as ` Get[StringJoin[
       StringDrop[NotebookFileName[SelectedNotebook[]], -3], ".m"]]],` seems to do.

Comment: Amm, now I have about 10 "Save and Run Demo" menu entries (as I've been playing around a bit). Is the last one used?

Comment: @rcollyer Yes you were right. The package get loaded. In fact after calling `?Function` the symbols in the package get their proper black highlight. Perhaps their is manual way of triggering the syntax highlighting update?

Comment: @Ajasja if there is, I don't know what it is.

Comment: Also, is there any good reason why I shouldn't change the short cut to Ctrl+s? I did and so far noting bad is happening:)

Comment: @ Ajasja - you can assign it as you like but some may conflict with Windows or Mathematica key combinations.

Comment: Thanks, I got it mostly working. Perhaps you also know the answers to two minor related subquestions: What's the difference between ``FrontEnd`KernelExecute` ``and `FrontEndExecute`? Why doesn't `NotebookEvaluate[SelectedNotebook[]];` work instead of `Get[...]`?

Comment: @ Ajasja - I have read `KernelExecute` and `FrontEndExecute` are the same, but think the latter may know some further commands specific to the front end.  To use `NotebookEvaluate` you need something like `NotebookEvaluate[SelectionMove[SelectedNotebook[], "All", Notebook]]` to specify what selection to evaluate.

Comment: @ChrisDegnen Thanks it works now. The `NotebookEvaluate[]` doesn't seem to work. But  putting a print in the notebook seems to wake up the syntax highlighter.