# Preserving indentation when creating a new line (when editing in a package)

Tags: front-end, packages

**Background:**
This is the third question in a row of questions about how to make editing packages in the front-end much more bearable (the other two are [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5417/running-a-package-automatically-when-its-saved) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5454/implementing-bookmarks-in-the-front-end-when-editing-a-package)). It seems that the front end is quite extensible, so I may not have to start using Workbench yet :)

When writing long blocks of code, proper indentation is invaluable. This is why most programming editors preserve the white space indentation when you enter a new line. So if you have three white spaces at the current line and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to move to a new line, it will also have three white spaces.

[image: Example image]

So my question is: **Is there a way to make the front-end preserve the white space indentation (when editing a package)?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have a palette including this button:

```
CreatePalette[{
  Button[
   "m-editor",
   Module[{modifyCodeStyle},(*by David Reiss*)

     modifyCodeStyle[nb_NotebookObject, Notebook] := 
      Module[{styledefs, editable}, 
       editable = Editable /. Options[nb, Editable];
       SetOptions[nb, Editable -> True];
       styledefs = StyleDefinitions /. Options[nb, StyleDefinitions];
       Switch[Head[styledefs], Notebook, 
        styledefs = 
         Notebook[{First@First[styledefs], 
           Cell[StyleData["Code"], PageWidth -> WindowWidth, 
            AutoIndent -> True, AutoSpacing -> True, 
            LineBreakWithin -> Automatic, LineIndent -> 1, 
            LinebreakAdjustments -> {0.85, 2, 10, 0, 1}], 
           Rest@First[styledefs]}, 
          Sequence @@ Rest[List @@ styledefs]], 
        String | FileName | FrontEnd`FileName, 
        styledefs = 
         Notebook[{Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> styledefs]], 
           Cell[StyleData["Code"], PageWidth -> WindowWidth, 
            AutoIndent -> True, AutoSpacing -> True, 
            LineBreakWithin -> Automatic, LineIndent -> 1, 
            LinebreakAdjustments -> {0.85, 2, 10, 0, 1}]}, 
          StyleDefinitions -> "PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"]];
       SetOptions[nb, StyleDefinitions -> styledefs];
       SetOptions[nb, Editable -> editable]];
     modifyCodeStyle[SelectedNotebook[], Notebook]];
   ]
  },
 WindowTitle -> "fix editor"
 ]
```

the code for which I lifted from [a post of David Reiss](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2009/Oct/msg00407.html) on the mathgroup.

To use it: open an m-editor, then click on the button. It will do what you want from there on. However, this must be repeated if you close and re-open the editor window.

Comment: +1 Is it perhaps possible to apply this automatically every time package is opened? Or to change the default style sheets for the m-editor?

Comment: I don't know how it is possible to do that. Perhaps someone else does have some ideas. For my part, this kind of annoyance led me to the workbench (which simply has a different set of annoyances!)

Comment: I had not seen this before, and I didn't know it could be done this way. +1!

Comment: One crude way of applying this fix automatically would be to pool (for example every one seconf) `Notebooks[]` using a `ScheduledTask` and apply this to any new *.m that are found. The code for would be put in an `init.m` somewhere. I don't know if there is a way to get notification form the front-end whenever a new file is opened. That method would be preferable to pooling...

Comment: I don't see *what* would get notified by the frontend if a new .m file was opened. You could try using `Dynamic` and having it do something whenever the list of open windows changes, but that doesn't work reliably if it's off-screen. But, perhaps there is some other way to get this to work always. although you'll quickly start getting annoyed again: construct your beautifully indented code and then attempt to wrap a `Total[]` (say) around it. You can't block-indent...

Comment: Good point, but perhaps a block-indent shortcut could be written as well. One would have to replace the selection with the indented version. Of course this would only be applicable to an m-editor.

Comment: Also, I've been trying to apply this using `SetOptions[$FrontEnd, ...]` but it doesn't seem to work.