# Running some code every time a new notebook is opened

Tags: front-end

**Is it possible to automatically execute some code every time a new notebook is opened?**

So for example I would like to print a message "New notebook" every time a new notebook is opened.

This question was prompted by this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5738/745) about fixing indentation when moving to a new line. The "fix" requires that some code is applied to the notebook every time it is opened. But I think this question in interesting enough to stand on it own.

I even have some working code, but it based on polling, so I would like to avoid that if possible. (also is it possible to get rid of the global variable `$OldNotebooks`?)

```
Clear[GetNewNotebooks, $OldNotebooks];
$OldNotebooks = Notebooks[];
GetNewNotebooks[] := 
  Module[{new}, 
   new = Complement[Notebooks[], $OldNotebooks]; $OldNotebooks = 
    Notebooks[]; new];
(*new=GetNewNotebooks[];*)

NBHistory = {}; Dynamic[NBHistory]

StartScheduledTask@
  CreateScheduledTask[NBHistory = NBHistory~Join~GetNewNotebooks[]];
```

Now every time you open a new notebook, it will get added to the list of NBHistory and displayed.

```
(*When you had enough:) *)
RemoveScheduledTask[ScheduledTasks[]]
```

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1113/121

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After a few modifications based on comments and chats with Ajasja and Szabolcs, this is the code:

```
i = 0; SetOptions[$FrontEndSession,
FrontEndDynamicExpression :>
Refresh[Notebooks[];
If[GetNewNotebooks[] =!= {}, Print["New one ", ++i]],
TrackedSymbols :> {}]]
```

The `Print` statement would be the code you want to run.

The `TrackedSymbols:>{}` setting of `Refresh` is there to prevent any external symbols introduced in your code that get changed inside the dynamic expression to trigger an update of `FrontEndDynamicExpression`. This can easily lead to infinite recursion as given in this example (**do not run this code unless you would like to crash your mma session**)

```
i = 0; SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, 
 FrontEndDynamicExpression :> (Notebooks[]; Print["New one ", i++])]
```

(Also perhaps the `Notebooks` built-in is handled specially, that is why this code works even though `TrackedSymbols` is set to {})