# Automatically switch Directory to NotebookDirectory?

Tags: notebooks, files-and-directories

On notebook edit, save, or opening I'd like to call `SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]`.

Using this [excellent answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5854/running-some-code-every-time-a-new-notebook-is-opened), I tried the obvious:

```
i = 0; SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, 
 FrontEndDynamicExpression :> Refresh[Notebooks[];
   If[CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {"NotebookFileName"}] != "", 
    SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]; 
    Print["Switching to notebook's directory", ++i]], 
   TrackedSymbols :> {}]]
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: what happens if you have several open notebooks associated with the same kernel?

Comment: @george2079 good question, I would like it to switch to the one you are currently editing

Comment: maybe define `$Pre` to check/set on every evaluation.   I prefer to keep it simple and put `SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]; ` before any code that depends on the path being set.

Comment: Does the solution below work for you?

Answer (score 2):

This code works, but you have to confirm the dynamic content evaluation when you open a notebook first time or simply evaluate anything.

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, 
 NotebookDynamicExpression :> Refresh[nb = InputNotebook[];
   If[EvaluationNotebook[] == nb && CurrentValue[nb, {"NotebookFileName"}] != "" && 
     Directory[] != NotebookDirectory[nb],
     SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[nb]];
    ], TrackedSymbols :> {}]]
```