# Execute code when it's saved

Tags: save

How do I execute code on save?

This is a similar question: [Running a package automatically when it's saved](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5417/running-a-package-automatically-when-its-saved)

Comment: But you seem to be familiar with this procedure. Could you elaborate more then?

Answer (score 0):

Evaluating the following in a notebook will place a "toolbar" as a [`DockedCell`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DockedCells.html) with a Save and Run button:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], DockedCells -> 
  Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[
    Row[
      {Button["Save and Run",
        Module[{},
          FrontEndTokenExecute[ButtonNotebook[], "Save"];
          NotebookFind[ButtonNotebook[], "Input", All, CellStyle];
          FrontEndTokenExecute[ButtonNotebook[], "EvaluateCells"]
        ]
       ]}, ImageSize -> Full, Alignment -> Right
    ]
   ]], 
  "DockedCell"
  ]
 ]
```

Afterwards, you can delete the above code, and then pressing this button will save the notebook before evaluating "Input" Cells.

Comment: Hmm. I was hoping there was an automatic way to do such.