# What are all the possible menu edits?

Tags: front-end, customization, menu

### Note:

I've discovered the menus are more-or-less as customizable as one would like, although it is mildly annoying to do this. Simply write your own `Menu` expression and use `FrontEndExecute@ResetMenusPacket[{expr}]`. If someone more expert has a better way, though, I would really like to know it.

For those glancing through, here is a minimal example of a dynamically editable menu-symbol:

```
$FEMenuRoot=Import[<your_MenuSetup.tr_file>];
$feStoredMenu = Automatic;
$FrontEndMenu := Replace[$feStoredMenu, Automatic -> $FEMenuRoot];
$FrontEndMenu /: 
  HoldPattern[Set[$FrontEndMenu, m : _Menu]] :=(
    $feStoredMenu = m;
    FrontEndExecute@ResetMenusPacket[{m}]
    );
$FrontEndMenu /: 
  HoldPattern[
   Set[$FrontEndMenu, Automatic]] :=
    (
     $feStoredMenu = Automatic; 
     FrontEndExecute@ResetMenusPacket[{Automatic}]);
$FrontEndMenu /: 
  HoldPattern[
   Unset[$FrontEndMenu]] :=
   ($FrontEndMenu = Automatic;);
```

Then do something like:

```
$FrontEndMenu =
  Menu["Mathematica",
   {
    Menu["DoopDoop", {
      MenuItem["Copy", "Copy", MenuKey["C", Modifiers -> {"Command"}]],
      MenuItem["Cut", "Cut", MenuKey["X", Modifiers -> {"Command"}]],
      MenuItem["Paste", "Paste", 
       MenuKey["V", Modifiers -> {"Command"}]],
      MenuItem["Save", "Save", MenuKey["S", Modifiers -> {"Command"}]],
      MenuItem["Save as WL",
       KernelExecute@
        FrontEndTokenExecute["SaveRename",
         {StringReplace[NotebookFileName[], ".nb" -> ".wl"], "Package"}
         ],
       MenuKey["S", Modifiers -> {"Command", "Shift"}],
       MenuEvaluator -> "Local",
       Method -> "Queued"
       ],
      MenuItem["Revert Menus",
       KernelExecute[$FrontEndMenu =.],
       MenuKey["R", Modifiers -> {"Command"}],
       MenuEvaluator -> "Local"]
      }],
    Menu["", {
      MenuItem["Musak",
       KernelExecute@
        SystemOpen@"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_lYx6dIKfos",
       MenuEvaluator -> "Local"
       ]
      }
     ]
    }];
```

And you have menus you can play with.

### Original Question:

So I've been playing with `` FrontEnd`AddMenuCommands `` recently and I wanted to figure out what all I could do with it.

There are a [number](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/915/38205) [of](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1607/38205) [answers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5417/running-a-package-automatically-when-its-saved/5418#5418) on this site to specific menu editing commands, but there is no general reference.

I've been able to figure out a bit from the source files, including making a useful reference graph of all the menus and submenus:

[image: Menu graph]

using the following code:

```
$MenuSetupTR = 
  FileNameJoin@{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", 
    "TextResources", "Macintosh", "MenuSetup.tr"};
$MenuStringsTR = 
  FileNameJoin@{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", 
    "TextResources", "MenuStrings.tr"};
$menuStructure = Import@$MenuSetupTR;
$menuStrings = Import@$MenuStringsTR;
$menuNames = 
  Cases[$menuStructure, (MenuItem[__, 
       name_String?(StringContainsQ["Dialog"])] | Menu[name_, ___]) :>
     name, ∞];
menuRules[Menu[name_, e_]] := Menu[name] -> menuRules@e;
menuRules[
   ignore : (_String | _MenuItem | Delimiter | _AlternateItems)] := 
  ignore;
SetAttributes[menuRules, Listable];
menuPart[menu_, name_] :=

  FirstCase[menu, Menu[name, _], None, ∞];
menuPart[menu_, name1_, names__] :=

  Fold[menuPart, menu, {name1, names}];
menuEdges[menu_] :=
  ReplaceAll[
   Cases[
     DeleteCases[menuRules@menu,
       Except[_Menu | _MenuItem | 
         Rule[_Menu, _] | _List | _String | _AlternateItems],
       ∞] //. {
       Rule[m_, expr : Except[_Rule]] :> Thread[m -> expr],
       Rule[m_Menu, Rule[subm_Menu, e_]] :> {m -> subm, subm -> e}
       },
     _Rule,
     ∞] // Flatten,
   Rule -> DirectedEdge];
menuGraph[menu_] :=
  With[{edges = menuEdges@menu},
   Graph[
    edges,
    VertexShape -> {
      Menu[n_] :> Graphics[Tooltip[{Hue[.1, .8, 1], Disk[]}, n]],
      m_MenuItem :> Graphics[Tooltip[{Hue[.6, .8, 1], Disk[]}, m]],
      e_AlternateItems :> 
       Graphics[Tooltip[{Hue[.4, .8, 1], Disk[]}, e]]
      }
    ]
   ];
menuGraph@$menuStructure
```

But I was hoping someone might know which of these menus are actually editable and what I can add to them. There are also the [dialogs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/915/38205), which I tried to scrape and found a few of and if someone could advise me on the use of these that would be a huge help too.

If this is too open ended, I'll refine the question, but in the meantime hopefully someone familiar with menu editing can help me out.

## ------ Update ------

Playing around with this I was able to find a way to more or less edit all the menus, but we have to do it manually. It takes a bit of work to do so.

My idea was to use `FrontEndExecute@ResetMenuPackets[{menu}]` and build the `menu` manually.

I created a special `$FrontEndMenu` symbol which basically routes `Set` to that (plus some utility code and whatnot).

Then create `Add`, `Insert`, `Drop`, `Take`, etc. commands to manipulate a `Menu` expression.

The toplevel menu expression needs to look like `Menu["Mathematica", {submenus}]` as best I can tell (anything else I tried crashed the system).

Then just save the basic menu expression from the MenuSetup.tr file (import it in the `` System` `` context) and work with that.

Doing this I've been able to completely my menus however I like:

[image: Menu rewrite]

Two issues: I don't know if this will work outside of Mac and it prevents the use of the `AddMenuComands` token.

Hopefully there's also a simpler way to do this... if anyone has better ways though that'd be great, otherwise this'll do for customization I guess.

Comment: [Andy Ross wrote](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/909/121): "*Controlling the placement with this method seems hard since there is no documentation on the topic.  It seems that `AddMenuCommands` takes a front end token as the first input and then attempts to find the first instance in `MenuSetup.tr` and replace immediately after that. I've spent about all the time I think its worth trying to figure out more and have come to the conclusion that if you want highly customized menus you will probably need to edit `MenuSetup.tr` directly.*"

Comment: So that's not completely true I think. You can manually set up a menu with `FrontEndExecute@ResetMenusPacket[{menuExpr}]`. I imported my MenuSetup.tr file, replaced the first argument of each `MenuItem` expresion with `"test"` and ran that through the `ResetMenusPacket` call and now all my menu items are `"test"`. Presumably you could maintain your own menu cache and do the resetting manually? It would be mildly annoying, but not too bad I think.

Comment: You'll be happy to know that you can add new menu segments with this. I added a `"Test"` bit before `"File"` like this.

Comment: One issue: this method seems to lock the menu to `AddMenuCommands`.