# Borked Find Window in OS X

Tags: front-end, mac-os-x

I've been having this happen to me on a daily basis with the Find & Replace window on OS X:

[image]

No text can be typed into the red regions, so all find & replace functionality is gone when this occurs. If you hover over the red regions, you can see the following error message:

> An unknown box name ($Aborted) was sent as the BoxForm for the expression.
>   Check the format rules for the expression.

The only solution to this, as far as I can tell, is to restart the kernel, which is fairly annoying. I recall that in previous versions of Mathematica (prior to 7), the Find & Replace window wasn't tied to the kernel at all, and this sort of thing would never occur. I think this is probably just a bug, but perhaps there is something I am doing in my code, perhaps setting a reserved variable that this window depends on, that is leading to the repeated recurrence of the problem.

Just wanted to see if anyone here has had experience with this issue (perhaps it's not just OS X specific), and if they had any tips on how to avoid it, or perhaps some remedies that don't involve a full kernel restart.

**Edit:** Here's a bit of code I used to stress-test a potential cause of this issue:

```
For[i = 1, i <= 100, i++,
    pal = CreatePalette[Dynamic@ProgressIndicator[progress]];
    progress = 0; cnt = 0;
    Do[cnt = cnt + 1; progress = cnt/100000, {j, 100000}];
    NotebookClose[pal];
]
```

Comment: please do not use the "bugs" tag unless the community has confirmed that it is indeed a bug. In this case, you haven't provided an example that can reproduce this behaviour, so we won't know if it is a bug or not...

Comment: OK, my mistake. I don't really know exactly how to reproduce the issue...it just seems to arise after having used Mathematica for a while. I was hoping someone else had encountered it under more controlled circumstances.

Comment: Just don't do what ever it is that you're doing that's messing with the ``FE`*`` symbols. All these application windows (find-replace/preferences/about) are notebooks and anything that you do to mess with the FrontEnd can mess the display here. As a simple example, ``Unprotect @@ Names["FE`*"];
Clear @@ Names["FE`*"];`` will reproduce this and mess up everything until you restart the kernel. Unless we know what exactly it is that you're doing, it's hard to diagnose.

Comment: Any idea how I could be messing with those symbols inadvertently? The only thing I can think of is that I use CreatePalette to produce a floating progress bar, which I then close when the calculation completes. Aside from that, I am not interacting with the FrontEnd in any obvious way.

Comment: Hmm... no, beats me. There are others here who know a lot more about the FrontEnd than I do and might be able to say something more useful (or at least, suggest ways to diagnose), but everyone's probably going to want some reproducible steps. Could you try (in a fresh kernel), creating and loading your palette, then using it, closing it and see if you can reproduce the error? If you can reproduce it in under 5 mins of activity/usage, then I'm sure people would appreciate that and be able to diagnose right away

Comment: Just tried stress-testing it with a bit of code that repeatedly creates and destroys the progress window, but was unable to reproduce it. Sorry that I can't be more helpful at the moment, I'll try to narrow it down.

Comment: I have had this same problem and have employed the same solution of restarting the kernel.  It occurs intermittently and I have as yet to identify a common sequence of events that leads to it.

Comment: If it was consistently happening, I'd say your front-end cache or init file was corrupt, as per this [comment](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4886/no-syntax-highlighting-of-package-functions#comment13359_4888). But, without it being consistent, I doubt that is the only cause.

Comment: It does occur on two separate machines for a wide variety of notebooks (although it does seem to occur more often if the calculations are particular processor/memory-intensive), so I'm skeptical that it's an isolated corruption issue.

Comment: When this happens, do you have Dynamic enabled and is a dynamic cell visible somewhere else in the notebook? I've never seen this - is it possible to click on the Plus sign at the top right of that dialog to see the error message?

Comment: I've attached the snippet of code I used to stress-test to the end of the question, which is the same bit of code I use to generate progress bars in my notebooks, and is the only Dynamic cell I have in my notebooks.

Comment: Just to provide an additional data point. This happens to me quite often too, and I don't do anything stressful or weird - compared with you folks anyway... No error messages or anything. [screen cap](http://i.stack.imgur.com/SqRWD.png)

Comment: For what it's worth, I have the same issue and I'm also not doing anything too taxing. I find that if I close the borked find window, it works on the second try. I'll be watching this closely as its an annoying problem!

Comment: Just had this happen to me in Mathematica 10. Copy/pasted an image into the notebook and all of a sudden Mathematica stalls and quits. Notice later that bringing up "Find" in Mac Terminal did the same, except that Mathematica code was being fed into the form field which stalled it. On "force quit" the Mac report feature showed some bizarre code. I ended up deleting Mathematica, searching for where vestiges remained. Found files remaining in /Users/Admin/Library/Mathematica/ and deleted them. It did the trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Troubleshooting on Mac OS X](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/TroubleshootingOnMacOSX.html):

> #### Front End Preferences
>
> Front end preferences, such as the locations of recently opened and
> saved files, are stored in a front end initialization file called
> init.m. This file is located in the directory
> ~/Library/Mathematica/FrontEnd. If you need to reset the front end
> preferences to their default values, hold down
> <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd> during startup. This will cause the
> initialization file to be rebuilt automatically.
>
> #### Caches
>
> Information about your Mathematica system layout, such as the
> locations of text resource files and help files, is stored in caches.
> These caches are located in the directory
> ~/Library/Mathematica/FrontEnd/7.0/Caches.
>
> A corrupted cache may cause the front end to produce an error or quit
> immediately on startup. The most convenient way to restore the caches
> to their default values is to hold down
> <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd> during startup. This will cause the
> Mathematica caches and the initialization file to be rebuilt
> automatically.
>
> If you want to rebuild your caches but retain your preferences, hold
> down <kbd>Shift</kbd> during startup. This will delete and rebuild the
> cache without rebuilding your front end initialization file.

Please try clearing cache, and if necessary preferences, and see if the problem persists.  In my experience most emergent *Mathematica* idiosyncrasies are tied to cache or preferences.

Comment: I'll give you the check for now, as it will probably take a few days before I'm sure this has resolved the problem. Hoping for the best!

Comment: @Guillochon thanks, but I suggest that you un-accept this answer, as the Accept may keep someone from posting the *real* solution, if this isn't it.

Comment: @Guillochon did your problem ever return?  If not, please again Accept this answer.  If it did I'll try to find another solution.

Comment: @MrWizard The problem has not returned yet, but I haven't been using Mathematica heavily the past week. I will accept the answer soon once I'm more confident that it resolves the problem.