# copy paste merging expressions

Tags: formatting

I ran a solve to evaluate a few linear equations,

```
Solve[{some eqns},{A0,B0,c0,d0,e0}]
```

and then in the output I got:

```
{{A0-> stuff+ 1/rho F (stuff) , B0->..,...,e0->..}}.
```

Now when when I selected, copied and pasted the expression I got for *A0*. I wound up getting :

```
stuff+ 1/rhoF (stuff)
```

My subsequent `ContourPlot` was giving me nothing and it took me the longest time to notice that two of my variables, $\rho$ and `F` had been made into a new variable `rhoF` somehow during the copy paste process.

I've found this to be a bit unnerving. Is there some way to guarantee that this never happens? I've been doing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd>. Should I do "copy as" and pick one of the options to avoid this formatting issue. Right now I don't have two variables that might merge together to become an pre-existing variable,  but if for example **rhoF** had indeed been something I had defined earlier, I would never have found out about this error and I would've been in deep trouble doing some corrupted analysis.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I tried the replace rule /. but I still have the same problem. This is what I have actually done:

```
{{A0, B0, L0, M0, c0, S}} = {A0, B0, L0, M0, c0, S} /. Solve[{
A0*(H0D)^(k1) +  B0*(H0D)^(k2) + (delta/(delta + rho - r))*(H0D) 
+ u/rho-  c0*F/rho ==-CF,
k1*A0*(H0D)^(k1 - 1) + k2*B0*(H0D)^(k2 - 1) == -((delta)/(delta + rho - r)),
L0*(H0S)^(k1) + M0*(H0S)^(k2) + c0*F/r == F,
L0*(H0D)^(k1) + M0*(H0D)^k2 + c0*F/r == H0D - CFL,
L0*H1R^(k1) + M0*H1R^k2 + c0*F/r -CRL == H1R - CFL + gamma*S,
A0*(H1R)^(k1) + B0*(H1R)^(k2) + (delta/(delta + rho - r))*(H1R) + 
u/rho - c0*F/rho -CR == -CF + (1 - gamma)*S}, {A0, B0, L0, M0, c0, S}]
```

and then when I tried to get the value for <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> A0, again rho and F were combined in line 16 to form rhoF. I tried to boldface it but I guess boldface does not work inside the code format. Please help!

```
-(-1/(delta - r + rho)
   delta (-H0D^
      k2 (-(-(-1 + gamma) H0S^k2 H1R^k1 + (-1 + gamma) H0S^k1 H1R^
            k2) (-((F H0D^k2)/r) + (F H0S^k2)/
          r) + (-H0D^k2 H0S^k1 + H0D^k1 H0S^k2) ((
          F (-1 + gamma) H1R^k2)/r + 
          H0S^k2 (-((F (-1 + gamma))/r) + (F gamma)/rho))) + (
    F gamma H0S^k2 (-H0D^k2 H0S^k1 + H0D^k1 H0S^k2) H1R^k2)/rho) +
 H0D^(-1 + k2)
  k2 (-(-(-(-1 + gamma) H0S^k2 H1R^k1 + (-1 + gamma) H0S^k1 H1R^
            k2) (-((F H0D^k2)/r) + (F H0S^k2)/
          r) + (-H0D^k2 H0S^k1 + H0D^k1 H0S^k2) ((
          F (-1 + gamma) H1R^k2)/r + 
          H0S^k2 (-((F (-1 + gamma))/r) + (F gamma)/rho))) (CF + (
      delta H0D)/(delta - r + rho) + u/rho) - 
   **1/rhoF** (-(F H0D^k2 + (CFL - H0D) H0S^k2) (-(-1 + gamma) H0S^
          k2 H1R^k1 + (-1 + gamma) H0S^k1 H1R^k2) + (-H0D^k2 H0S^
          k1 + H0D^k1 H0S^k2) (-F (-1 + gamma) H1R^k2 + 
         H0S^k2 (-(-1 + gamma) (CFL - CRL - H1R) - 
            gamma (CF - CR + (delta H1R)/(delta - r + rho) + u/
               rho))))))/(H0D^(-1 + k2)
  k2 (-H0D^
     k1 (-(-(-1 + gamma) H0S^k2 H1R^k1 + (-1 + gamma) H0S^k1 H1R^
           k2) (-((F H0D^k2)/r) + (F H0S^k2)/
         r) + (-H0D^k2 H0S^k1 + H0D^k1 H0S^k2) ((
         F (-1 + gamma) H1R^k2)/r + 
         H0S^k2 (-((F (-1 + gamma))/r) + (F gamma)/rho))) + (
   F gamma H0S^k2 (-H0D^k2 H0S^k1 + H0D^k1 H0S^k2) H1R^k1)/rho) - 
H0D^(-1 + k1)
  k1 (-H0D^
     k2 (-(-(-1 + gamma) H0S^k2 H1R^k1 + (-1 + gamma) H0S^k1 H1R^
           k2) (-((F H0D^k2)/r) + (F H0S^k2)/
         r) + (-H0D^k2 H0S^k1 + H0D^k1 H0S^k2) ((
         F (-1 + gamma) H1R^k2)/r + 
         H0S^k2 (-((F (-1 + gamma))/r) + (F gamma)/rho))) + (
   F gamma H0S^k2 (-H0D^k2 H0S^k1 + H0D^k1 H0S^k2) H1R^k2)/rho))
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE, Amatya! I have formatted your post so it is a bit easier to read. If you would like to know how to do this yourself, [this page explains how](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Comment: Hi Verbeia, thanks a lot for fixing my post and linking to the guide!

Comment: Hi Nasser,

Something strange is happening. The merge of the two variable remained after I tried your /. replace rule.

Comment: HI Nasser, please see my edited question, the stuff in the end. I have written the actual Solve and the actual expression where the weirdness is happening.

Comment: I don't seem to have this problem with version 7 but that sure sounds nasty!  Before you conclude it is a bug, please try [clearing your preferences.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5703/121)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *apparent* concatenation of symbols seems to be related to the page width (window width) at the time when the output expression is generated.

Using

```
A0 /. Solve[{ A0*(H0D)^(k1) +  B0*(H0D)^(k2) + (delta/(delta + rho - r))*(H0D)  + u/rho-  c0*F/rho ==-CF, k1*A0*(H0D)^(k1 - 1) + k2*B0*(H0D)^(k2 - 1) == -((delta)/(delta + rho - r)), L0*(H0S)^(k1) + M0*(H0S)^(k2) + c0*F/r == F, L0*(H0D)^(k1) + M0*(H0D)^k2 + c0*F/r == H0D - CFL, L0*H1R^(k1) + M0*H1R^k2 + c0*F/r -CRL == H1R - CFL + gamma*S, A0*(H1R)^(k1) + B0*(H1R)^(k2) + (delta/(delta + rho - r))*(H1R) +  u/rho - c0*F/rho -CR == -CF + (1 - gamma)*S}, {A0, B0, L0, M0, c0, S}]
```

one can replicate OP's issue (on Windows Vista 64bit MMA 8.0.4) by changing the window width between evaluations of the above expression.

Starting with a wide enough window (e.g., 1550 pixels), I get the following:

[image]

If the window width at the time the input cell is evaluated is smaller (e.g., 1000 pixels) I get

[image]

However, what appears as `1/rhoF` is actually `1/rho F`. This can be seen by copying the larger term containing it and then processing it with `ToBoxes`, `InputForm`, `FullForm`, `StandardForm` or `TraditionalForm`:

[image]

Finally, depending on whether or not the white space to the right of `F` is included in the copied expression, copy-paste using `Ctrl-C` `Ctrl-V` gives two different results:

When the white space is not highlighted,

[image]

you get the two symbols `rho` and `F` concatenated into a new symbol `rhoF`; using `ToBoxes` on the pasted expression:

```
 1/rhoF // ToBoxes
 (* FractionBox["1", "rhoF"]  *)
```

If the copied piece includes the white space to the right of `F`:

[image]

copy-paste gives the correct result:

```
 1/rho F // ToBoxes
 (* FractionBox["F", "rho"] *)
```

Comment: Thanks for responding Kguler. I tried  
    ClearAll[A0, B0, L0, M0, c0, S]
 and
 Solve but it still produces rhoF on my machine. I guess this is some quirk of my particular machine or my particular mathematica. I will try restarting my computer to see if anything changes.

Comment: Amatya,  I get the same result as you do if I don't start from a fresh kernel. This seems to be a bug in typesetting routines: The output of `Solve` is typeset with `rhoF` even without copy-paste. Starting from fresh kernel solved the issue on my system (Vista 64bit, 8G mem, MMA 8.0.4).

Comment: Amatya, please see the updated post. It turns out the puzzling behavior has nothing to do with restarting MMA or fresh kernel (it so happened that I resized the window at the same time as re-started the kernel).

Comment: Oh man! That's pretty cool that you spotted that Kguler!! Thanks a lot. I will keep my windows maxed from here on. When I was copying and pasting, I was copying the entire expression and not just the rhoF part but I guess somehow somewhere the copying was literal and the information, that mathematica was saving on space by writing them next to each other, was lost.